# Windows 10 - can't view some websites

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, browser, proxy

I've ran 6 different malware cleaners. Reset proxy settings. Reset network settings. Statically set IP Addresses. I can ping and resolve hostnames.

However, opening up web browsers Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE, all have issues opening websites like google.com but can open some websites. Other machines work fine so I know it is locally to this machine.

I run and manage the network. The error I am getting is not a 404 but can't find the server at xxx domain. It act's like there is a proxy but all the proxy settings are not set or disabled.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup google.com 
Non-authoritative answer:

Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4008:80b::200e
      216.58.219.174
```

Edit:

Tried a new account. No success. Set both DNS fields to Google. The system is also fully up-to-date

IS there anything else I can try to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?  When you say you can't access google.com what do you mean exactly?  Do you mean you get a, (404 error page, not responding, ect).  Being able to ping a hostname and being able to navigate to the website hosted on the server from a security perspective are two entirely different things.  Trivial action as an Administrator to allow one action and not the other.

Comment: What happens if you do a `nslookup` on google.com?

Comment: No proxies and I disabled all the proxy settings. The kicker is some websites work just fine but other don't. domains resolve to the correct IPs as well

Comment: @Ramhound C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup google.com 
Non-authoritative answer:

Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4008:80b::200e
   216.58.219.174

Comment: Update your question;  Have changed the DNS servers to some other provider?

Comment: DNS server IPs are the local router and then 8.8.8.8 for Google.

Comment: On one of the problem clients, change the DNS servers to just Google, eliminate the router from the equation at least when it comes to the DNS.  The next step, would have the router assign the client a static ip address, and remove it's DHCP service entirely from the equation.

Comment: [DNS - NSLOOKUP what is the meaning of the non-authoritative answer?](http://serverfault.com/questions/413124/dns-nslookup-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-non-authoritative-answer)

Comment: If you assign 2 DNS servers as DNS server and the first one responds even though the answer given is incorrect, the second one is never contacted. So 8.8.8.8 is not used at all. I would start restarting the router. It will likely fix your issues.

Comment: @LPChip - My suggestion takes the router's DNS out of the equation for the time being.  Netgear has a huge exploit they recently confirmed in the news.  Many malicious things could be going on with the router.

Comment: "The system is also fully up-to-date" this means your using x.576?

Comment: Test on your phone as its a different network (I know it's an old post but this comment may help others)

Answer (score 1):

- `sfc /scannow`
- Login as a different user.
- Patch Tuesday is today, 12/13/2016. Did you update? [Is there an update the broke something](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1947569-spark-latest-windows-10-update-causes-some-users-to-lose-internet-connection)?
- "[Users around the world are reporting that they are no longer able to connect to the internet after applying a Windows Update.](http://www.myce.com/news/users-around-world-lose-internet-connection-windows-update-fix-81047/)"
- `ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew`

> Users around the world are reporting that they are no longer able to
> connect to the internet after applying a Windows Update. They receive
> the error ‘Wi-Fi doesn’t have a valid IP configuration’. Several ISPs
> around the world report about the issue and they report Microsoft is
> aware of the issue too. Fortunately there is a simple solution
> available.  The British provider Virgin Media writes on its support
> page, **“Some Windows 10 users are experiencing difficulty connecting
> to the internet after installing the latest update. In most cases the
> IP address is now starting 169…”**

[Users around the world lose internet connection after Windows Update (with fix)](http://www.myce.com/news/users-around-world-lose-internet-connection-windows-update-fix-81047/)

> Have a look at reserved IP address [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) under special use IPv4:

> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block.  As described in
> [RFC3927], it is allocated for communication between hosts on a
> single link.  Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration,
> such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.

[Why is Windows' default IP address 169.xx.xx.xx?](https://superuser.com/questions/238625/why-is-windows-default-ip-address-169-xx-xx-xx)

In other words, the update in question, is causing people systems to be unable to connect to their DHCP server.

Comment: I know for a fact it's not related to the massive issue Microsoft broke with Windows Update.

Comment: I am tempted to submit an answer, that is an exact duplicate as this answer, in order to do a teachable lesson.  A bunch of links are not acceptable, but at the end of the day, I can't justify hitting submit when I know the update isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: @MadTomVane - I went ahead and quoted the relevant information from your link, I then explained the behavior of the "bug" caused by the update, if you don't approve of the change you can revert the change yourself.  *If you do that be sure you quote and cite the relevant information from your links yourself.*  You should read the help center in order to better understand what makes a good answer here at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for the improvements and feedback. I'll do that for future answers.

Comment: The update in question is more than a week old now and a new update was released to fix the issue. In addition, it causes windows to lose its entire network, not just unable to not visit 6 sites. So I have to agree with @Ramhound, this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an ISP issue. After calling them it was determined to be a problem relating to them.