# wlan0 bridge to eth0 works but eth0 gets no internet

Tags: bridge, hostapd

I am attempting to configure a linux box to use the wlan0 interface as an access point using hostapd. eth0 is the only ethernet port that is connected to a router.  I am able to connect to the access point and it receives internet access however when hostapd is running and the wlan0 interface is up, I am unable to access the internet on the box itsself (unable to SSH into it and unable to update the NTP).

**Topology**
br0 = eth0 + wlan0 &&
br0 stp = ON &&
linux ipv4_forward ENABLED

**Netfilter**
NO iptables or ebtables rules are in effect (all ACCEPT)

Here is the contents of **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
pre-up ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
pre-up ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 up
pre-up brctl addbr br0
pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
post-down ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 down
post-down ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
post-down brctl delif br0 eth0
post-down brctl delbr br0
```

Here is the output of **brctl show**

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.00c0ca8ffbc5       yes             eth0
                                                        wlan0
```

Here is the contents of /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0

driver=nl80211
country_code=US
hw_mode=a
beacon_int=100

#NON DFS CHAN:  36, 40, 44, 48, 149, 153, 157, 161
channel=149

ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
ht_capab=[HT20][HT40]

ssid=Raspberry
wpa_passphrase=friendlyap
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Here is the output for **ip route show**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0  metric 204
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.22.129  metric 202
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.106  metric 204
```

Output of **ifconfig**

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:9298 (9.0 KiB)  TX bytes:10357 (10.1 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:169.254.22.129  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:9298 (9.0 KiB)  TX bytes:17208 (16.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:98 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:7569 (7.3 KiB)
```

Where 192.168.1.1 is the router's IP.

If I run the following commands, I am able to access the box's SSH and update the NTP.

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
service hostapd stop
```

My suspicion is that the route table is incorrect or one of the entries has an invalid metric.  I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: I have found [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point#Bridge_setup), it says [emphasis mine]: "You need to create a network bridge and add your network interface (e.g. `eth0`) to it. You **should not** add the wireless device (e.g. `wlan0`) to the bridge; `hostapd` will add it on its own." I can't confirm your bridge setup would interfere, I don't know `hostapd` good enough to be sure – that's why it's only a comment, not an answer. Nevertheless you may try following this lead.

Comment: Also your `eth0` has [link local address](https://superuser.com/a/238632/432690). I guess it shouldn't as a part of a bridge.